# iOS app build fail on App Center: Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods, afhttpclient

My app is failing to build on App Center with the following errors:

```
/Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx/Lib/Api/ApiClient.swift:137:67: error: missing argument for parameter 'headers' in call
                                            parameters: parameters,
                                                                  ^
                                                                  , headers: <#[String : String]?#>
__ObjC.AFHTTPSessionManager:12:15: note: 'get(_:parameters:headers:progress:success:failure:)' declared here
    open func get(_ URLString: String, parameters: Any?, headers: [String : String]?, progress downloadProgress: ((Progress) -> Void)?, success: ((URLSessionDataTask, Any?) -> Void)?, failure: ((URLSessionDataTask?, Error) -> Void)? = nil) -> URLSessionDataTask?
              ^
/Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx/Lib/Api/ApiClient.swift:143:68: error: missing argument for parameter 'headers' in call
                                             parameters: parameters,
                                                                   ^
                                                                   , headers: <#[String : String]?#>
__ObjC.AFHTTPSessionManager:18:15: note: 'post(_:parameters:headers:progress:success:failure:)' declared here
    open func post(_ URLString: String, parameters: Any?, headers: [String : String]?, progress uploadProgress: ((Progress) -> Void)?, success: ((URLSessionDataTask, Any?) -> Void)?, failure: ((URLSessionDataTask?, Error) -> Void)? = nil) -> URLSessionDataTask?
              ^
/Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx/Lib/Api/ApiClient.swift:149:69: error: missing argument for parameter 'headers' in call
                                              parameters: parameters,
                                                                    ^
                                                                    , headers: <#[String : String]?#>
__ObjC.AFHTTPSessionManager:27:15: note: 'patch(_:parameters:headers:success:failure:)' declared here
    open func patch(_ URLString: String, parameters: Any?, headers: [String : String]?, success: ((URLSessionDataTask, Any?) -> Void)?, failure: ((URLSessionDataTask?, Error) -> Void)? = nil) -> URLSessionDataTask?
              ^
/Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx/Lib/Api/ApiClient.swift:154:70: error: missing argument for parameter 'headers' in call
                                               parameters: parameters,
                                                                     ^
                                                                     , headers: <#[String : String]?#>
__ObjC.AFHTTPSessionManager:30:15: note: 'delete(_:parameters:headers:success:failure:)' declared here
    open func delete(_ URLString: String, parameters: Any?, headers: [String : String]?, success: ((URLSessionDataTask, Any?) -> Void)?, failure: ((URLSessionDataTask?, Error) -> Void)? = nil) -> URLSessionDataTask?
              ^
              ^
```

and

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal arm64
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

The code in question:

```
        switch method {
            case "GET":
                requestOperation = self.get(URL,
                                            parameters: parameters,
                                            progress: nil,
                                            success: baseSuccessBlock,
                                            failure: baseFailureBlock)
            case "POST":
                requestOperation = self.post(URL,
                                             parameters: parameters,
                                             progress: nil,
                                             success: baseSuccessBlock,
                                             failure: baseFailureBlock)
            case "PATCH":
                requestOperation = self.patch(URL,
                                              parameters: parameters,
                                              success: baseSuccessBlock,
                                              failure: baseFailureBlock)
            case "DELETE":
                requestOperation = self.delete(URL,
                                               parameters: parameters,
                                               success: baseSuccessBlock,
                                               failure: baseFailureBlock)
            default:
                requestOperation = nil
        }
```

The app successfully builds on my local machine in Xcode. My build setting locally are:

- iOS Deployment Target: 11.0
- Swift Language version: 5

Other info:

- Xcode version: 11.6
- AFNetworking Pod Version: 3.2.1
- MacOS version: Catalina 10.15.6
- Cocoapods Version: 1.7.5

The Xcode version on App Center under the build settings is also set to 11.6.

It seems to be an issue with the AFNetworking pod, but I get an error in Xcode when adding the `headers` argument: `Extra argument 'headers' in call`

Comment: The issue seems to have been that a different version of the AFNetworking pod was used to build on App Center. In my podfile I replaced `pod 'AFNetworking'` with `pod 'AFNetworking', '3.2.1'` and the build was successful on App Center after the change was pushed